# Maven overrides configuration in profiles plugin

Tags: maven

I have a 3 maven profiles with plugins:

```
<profile>
   <id>first</id>
   <build>
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
           ...
        <configuration>
           <var>1</var>
        </configuration>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </build>    
</profile>

<profile>
   <id>second</id>
   <build>
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
           ...
        <configuration>
           <var>2</var>
        </configuration>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </build>    
</profile>

<profile>
   <id>third</id>
   <build>
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
           ...
        <configuration>
           <var>3</var>
        </configuration>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </build>    
</profile>
```

When i start my build with mvn clean install -P first,second,third -X, I discovered that all this plugins was executed with configuration from from third profile. Is there any way to preserve my configuration for each of my plugins and not to be overriden by third configuration?

Comment: You probably need 3 different execution for each profile

Comment: @JigarJoshi what parameters do you exactly mean? i have 3 different of executions (supposedly) like this ? for each plugin in profile of course: 
     `<executions>
 <execution>
 <id>some_id</id>
 <phase>generate-sources</phase>
 <goals>
     <goal>replace</goal>
 </goals>                   
       </execution>
     </executions>`

Comment: I mean `mvn clean install -P first`, `mvn clean install -P second`, `mvn clean install -P third`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152831/building-multiple-maven-profiles-for-a-single-jenkins-job

Comment: I don't think I can use this solution, because it is a GWT project, i can't afford it to compile several times. But i think about it, maybe it will work somehow. Thanks!

Comment: you don't need to compile both of the time, you can skip compilation in second and third profile

Comment: @JigarJoshi could you please tell me how? i'm a newbie when it comes to maven.

Comment: using [`mainSkip`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#skipMain) proeprty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments section, You would have to invoke 3 build activating each profile differently

for example

```
mvn clean install -Pfirst
mvn clean install -Psecond
mvn clean install -Pthird
```

and to disable compilation in second and third, you could configure maven-compiler-plugin for these profiles and use [`skipMain`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#skipMain) property to disable main's source compilation, also for tests